# Cant't get recursion go deeper in Yaml parsing

Tags: python, python-3.x, recursion, yaml

I have a yaml file which I parse. I use a simple recursive function but does not work as I expected. If I call `parse(content, 'mydrive/home/sample/aaaaa1.html')` I get the result `home/sample/aaaaa1.html`. However, `parse(content, 'mydrive/home/sample/sample3.html')` returns `None`.

What am I doing wrong?

```
from ruamel.yaml import YAML as yaml

content = yaml().load(open(r'/home/doc/sample.yaml', 'r'))

def parse(content, path):
    """
    Parse the YAML.
    """
    for i in content:
        if isinstance(i, dict):
            for item in i:
                if item == 'href':
                    if i[item] in path:
                        return i[item]
                elif item == 'topics':
                    return parse(i[item], path)
                elif item == 'placeholder':
                    pass
                else:
                    print("I did not recognize", item)
        else:
            print("---- not a dictionary ----")
```

Here is the sample yaml:

```
- placeholder: Sample
- topics:

    - placeholder: Sample
    - topics:
        - placeholder: Sample
        - topics:
            - href: home/sample/aaaaa1.html
            - href: home/sample/aaaaa2.html

    - placeholder: Sample
    # Comment
    - topics:     
        - href: home/sample/sample1.html
        - href: home/sample/sample2.html
        - href: home/sample/sample3.html
```

Comment: Hmm not sure to understand what you are trying to do, but you really looks like somebody that wants to use [pyyaml](http://pyyaml.org/). Why are you not just using this lib (or the one you imported in your code) to parse yaml?

Comment: @Arount, the `ruamel.yaml` module is basically a superset of `PyYAML`.

Comment: @marw, what exactly are you trying to accomplish?

Comment: @larsks call i.g. `parse(content, 'mydrive/home/sample/sample3.html')` and get `home/sample/sample3.html` as the output. Btw, I am adding line on how I load the content.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

## The problem:

Your `parse()` function never hits the last branch of the topic in the tree.  In particular, when it hits this line:

```
elif item.startswith('topics'):
    return parse(i[item], path)
```

It'll only dive *further* into the inner layers but doesn't know how to get back out because you're always returning `parse()` of the inner items.  To demonstrate, if you add this `else` line in:

```
if item == 'href':
    if i[item] in path:
        return i[item]
    else:  #Add this
        return "I can't get out" #Add this
```

You'll realize your second call for `sample3.html` is returning "I can't get out" because that's the end of your return chain.  It's returning `None` right now there's no `else` if the item doesn't match the path.

## The fix:

A simple fix is change your `topics` handling as follows:

```
elif item == 'topics':
    result = parse(i[item], path)
    if result: return result
```

So that you always check if the inner `parse()` returns something.  If it doesn't, *don't return* and continue on with the next item on the outer layer.

## The Output:

```
home/sample/aaaaa1.html
home/sample/sample3.html
```

## My 2 cents:

I debugged this by adding 1/2/3 to your topics/placeholders and follow the debugger to see where the iteration stopped.  It helps visualize the problem.  IMHO (still a beginner) a cleaner way to do this is assign a return value in each check, but only return the value at the very end of the function so you avoid this debugging mess.  BTW, thanks for this question.  It's a learning process for me as well, and I learned the cautions of recursive functions.  This is how I would have coded `parse()`:

```
def parse(content, path):
    """
    Parse the YAML.
    """
    for i in content:
        result = None  # Default result to None so the return won't trigger.
        if isinstance(i, dict):
            for item in i:
                if item == 'href':
                    if i[item] in path:
                        result = i[item]  # Assign value instead of returning
                elif item == 'topics':
                    result = parse(i[item], path)  # Assign value instead of returning
                elif item == 'placeholder':
                    pass
                else:
                    print("I did not recognize", item)
        else:
            print("---- not a dictionary ----") 
        if result: return result    # only return something if it has found a match.
```

I also would update the two `print()` statements to actually handle the condition if it means something to your program.  Printing is mostly useless I find unless you are debugging or want to monitor your console.  I would either log them or return *something* to your program so the condition doesn't get pass unnoticed.